# QField camera pics not able to save

Tags: qfieldsync

I'm using a Samsung Ultra 23 to collect points and a photo for each point. The file has saved with a long name and is not visible. The attachment files with photo names are showing but the format us not usable.

This happened a few years ago and I was able to fix it but now it's giving some serious headaches.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.